# Number of items combination in r

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a purchase data with amount of each brand that every customer bought. My dt_groupped looks likes this:

| ID | Brand | nr_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand1 | 1 |
| 1 | Brand2 | 2 |
| 2 | Brand1 | 3 |
| 2 | Brand2 | 2 |
| 2 | Brand3 | 5 |

I want to calculate the matrix where I will have information how many times a combination of every 2 brands was purchased by each household (Like Brand 1 & Brand 2 was purchased 5 times by ID = 2, I don't want split by more variables like Brand 1 & Brand 2 % Brand 3)

My expected output is:

| ID | Brand | nr_purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand1 | 1 |
| 1 | Brand2 | 2 |
| 1 | Brand1 & Brand2 | 3 |
| 2 | Brand1 | 3 |
| 2 | Brand2 | 2 |
| 2 | Brand3 | 5 |
| 2 | Brand1 & Brand2 | 5 |
| 2 | Brand2 & Brand3 | 7 |
| 2 | Brand1 & Brand3 | 8 |

I tried this code:

```
dt_grouped <- dt %>% group_by(ID, Brand) %>% 
  summarise(nr_purchases = sum(nr_products_bought))

# Create a new data table with the combinations of brands for each ID
dt_result <- data.table()
for (id in unique(dt$ID)) {
  brands <- dt_grouped[ID == id, Brand]
  brands <- paste(brands, collapse = ", ")
  nr_purchases <- sum(dt_grouped[ID == id, nr_purchases])
  dt_result <- rbind(dt_result, data.table(ID = id, Brand = brands, nr_purchases = nr_purchases))
}
```

But unfortunately is giving me an error: "in dt_groupped[ID == id, Brand] object HHKEY, Brand not found"
Do you know how why is that error occuring?/ Maybe is there more efficient way of coding this.

Thank you for helping

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a self-join based approach:

```
combos = merge(dt, dt, by = "ID", allow.cartesian = TRUE)[
  Brand.x < Brand.y,
][
  ,
  c("nr_purchases", "Brand") := list(
    nr_purchases.x + nr_purchases.y,
    paste(Brand.x, Brand.y, sep = " & ")
  )
][
  , c("ID", "Brand", "nr_purchases")
]

rbind(dt, combos)
#    ID           Brand nr_purchases
# 1:  1          Brand1            1
# 2:  1          Brand2            2
# 3:  2          Brand1            3
# 4:  2          Brand2            2
# 5:  2          Brand3            5
# 6:  1 Brand1 & Brand2            3
# 7:  2 Brand1 & Brand2            5
# 8:  2 Brand1 & Brand3            8
# 9:  2 Brand2 & Brand3            7
```

Comment: Very elegant, indeed...!

Answer (score 2):

3 minutes too late... Here is an answer using data.table.

```
require("data.table")

data <- data.table(data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  Brand = c("Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3"),
  nr_purchases = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

data[, {
  tb <- tapply(nr_purchases, Brand, sum)
  cm <- combn(Brand, 2)
  list(Brand        = apply(cm, 2, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = " & ")),
       nr_purchases = apply(cm, 2, function(x) sum(tb[x])))
}, by = .(ID)]

#    ID           Brand nr_purchases
# 1:  1 Brand1 & Brand2            3
# 2:  2 Brand1 & Brand2            5
# 3:  2 Brand1 & Brand3            8
# 4:  2 Brand2 & Brand3            7
```

Answer (score 1):

With `combn`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  reframe(result = combn(seq_along(nr_purchases), 2, function(i)
    list(Brand = paste(Brand[i], collapse = " & "),
         nr_purchases = sum(nr_purchases[i])),
    simplify = FALSE), .by = ID) %>% 
  unnest_wider(result) %>% 
  bind_rows(df, .)

  ID           Brand nr_purchases
1  1          Brand1            1
2  1          Brand2            2
3  2          Brand1            3
4  2          Brand2            2
5  2          Brand3            5
6  1 Brand1 & Brand2            3
7  2 Brand1 & Brand2            5
8  2 Brand1 & Brand3            8
9  2 Brand2 & Brand3            7
```